# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac {-1}{2} (1+\frac{1}{n})(1^1\cdot 2^2\cdots n^n)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}$

Tags: limits

The question is to evaluate  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac {-1}{2} (1+\frac{1}{n})(1^1\cdot 2^2\cdots n^n)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$

I tried to take ln both sides and apply the formula for Riemann sum but I failed to bring it in the form required.Any hint to bring the limit into some known form shall be highly appreciated .Thanks.

Comment: navinstudent did u mean $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac {-1}{2} (1+\frac{1}{n})}(1^1\cdot 2^2\cdots n^n)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$A_n=\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)\left( \prod_{k=1}^n k^k\right)^{1/n^2} \ge 1$$
you have
$$0 \le n^{-\frac{1}{2}A_n} \le n^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \to 0$$
so by the squeeze theorem your limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you please explain how did you get $A_n \geq 1$

Comment: It is a product of numbers larger than $1$.

Comment: Please, explain why you don't accept this solution. Aren't you confident with squeeze theorem?

Comment: Sorry for my previous comments.squeeze theorem is very well applicable here.Thanks.